# How to show PDF in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]I have a service call and then I mapped data content  into my model

```
   public byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

then I need to add a property in my view model and then it needs to bind to view. the problem is I can not figure out which XAML code I need to bind to get this content to show

when debugged and checked it has data. The problem is how I show this content In view(Using XAML). I need to show these content in view page what should I use and How to do this

Comment: Please give the detail of data you get. Also explain how to want to show that. You can use a paper and pencil to sketch the view. Than someone will able to help you

Comment: Okay I will do that